# Rich:Editor - com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: jsf-2, ckeditor, editor, richfaces

I'm facing an annoyng problem and i hope someone can help me.
I'm using *JSF 2.0*, *Mojarra 2.0.9* and *RichFaces 4.3.0_final*.
Trying to add a **Rich Faces Editor** into a jspf page, but when the page is loaded i have the error below.
If i refresh the browser page the editor is displayed.

This is my **jspf page** that cause the error ("myEditorValue" is a java.lang.String):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:richext="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    
    <script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH='#{request.contextPath}/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces.ckeditor/';</script>    
    
    <h:panelGrid id="myPanel-main" rendered="#{myBean.rendered}" style="width: 100%;">
       
       <h:form id="myPanel-form">
            <rich:collapsiblePanel id="myPanel-loadCollapse" rendered="#{not myBean.loadDone}" header="My Header" style="width:100%;">
                <h:graphicImage id="myPanel-loading" value="#{user.layout.ajaxLoadingBar}" style="text-align:center;" />
            </rich:collapsiblePanel>
            
            <h:panelGroup id="myPanel-data" rendered="#{myBean.loadDone}" layout="block">
               
               <c:forEach var="proposal" items="#{myBean.clientHistoryKeySet}">
               
                   <rich:collapsiblePanel id="myPanel-loadDone" style="width:100%;" rendered="#{not empty myBean.clientHistory[proposal]}"
                                          header="Header - #{proposal.id} - (#{proposal.stateproposal})" expanded="#{myBean.expandedSection}"
                                          headerClass= "#{myBean.selectedProp == proposal.id ? myBean.highlightHeader : ''}">
               
                   <h:panelGrid id="myPanel-history" columns="8" style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
                        <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_1" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_2}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_3}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_4}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_5}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_6}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_7}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                          <h:outputText value="#{user.message.MSG_ID_8}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class = "headerField"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        
                        <c:forEach var="dat" items="#{myBean.clientHistory[proposal]}">
                            
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                               <h:graphicImage url= "#{dat.pathColor}" width="45%" height="45%" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                              <h:outputText value="#{dat.date1}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;"></h:outputText>
                           </h:panelGroup>
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dat.amount1}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;"></h:outputText>
                           </h:panelGroup>
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dat.date2}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;"></h:outputText>
                           </h:panelGroup>
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                               <h:outputText value="#{dat.date3}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;"> </h:outputText>     
                            </h:panelGroup>
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                              <h:outputText value="#{dat.amount2}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;"></h:outputText>
                           </h:panelGroup>
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dat.figure}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;"></h:outputText>
                           </h:panelGroup>
                           <h:panelGroup style="float:center">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dat.user}" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%;"></h:outputText>
                           </h:panelGroup>
                           
                        </c:forEach>
                        
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    
                    <c:forEach var="dat" items="#{myBean.clientHistory[proposal]}">
                            
                        <rich:collapsiblePanel id="myPanel-Editor" rendered="true" switchType="client" 
                            header="Editor Commerciale" style="width:100%;" expanded="false">
                            <h:panelGroup id="myPanel-SaveEditor">
                                <a4j:commandLink action="#{dat.saveEditor}" style="margin-left:10px;text-decoration:none;"
                                    onclick="this.style.display='none'" type="button" render="@this myPanel-SaveEditor" status="myPanel-SavingEditor">
                                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/salva.gif"/>
                                    <h:outputText value="Salva" 
                                    style="margin-left:10px;font-size:14px;line-height: 20px;color:#274449;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:bottom;" />
                                </a4j:commandLink>
                                <a4j:status name="myPanel-SavingEditor">
                                    <f:facet name="start">
                                        <h:graphicImage value="#{user.layout.ajaxLoadingBar}" style="z-index:1000;"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </a4j:status>
                                <h:graphicImage rendered="#{dat.editorSaved}" style="margin-left:15px;" value="/images/imm_ok.gif"/>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <br /><br />
                            <rich:editor id="myEditor" value="#{dat.myEditorValue}" />
                        </rich:collapsiblePanel>

                    </c:forEach>
                
                 </rich:collapsiblePanel>
    
               </c:forEach>
               
          </h:panelGroup>
       
       </h:form>
       
       <a4j:jsFunction name="loadmyPanel" actionListener="#{myBean.load}" render="myPanel-form" execute="@this" immediate="true" />   
       <script type="text/javascript">loadmyPanel();</script>
    
    </h:panelGrid>
    
</ui:composition>
```

Stacktrace:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id javax_faces_location_BODY.  Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;.
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$1.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1507)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1518)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.VisitUtils.doFullNonIteratingVisit(VisitUtils.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:448)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at it.uniteam.timeojsf.util.ApplicationSessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(ApplicationSessionExpiryFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1427)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$1.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:265)
    ... 41 more
javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id javax_faces_location_BODY.  Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;.
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$1.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1507)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1518)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.VisitUtils.doFullNonIteratingVisit(VisitUtils.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:448)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at it.uniteam.timeojsf.util.ApplicationSessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(ApplicationSessionExpiryFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1427)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$1.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:265)
    ... 41 more
giu 24, 2020 8:19:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/myApplication] threw exception [com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1427)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$1.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:265)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1507)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1518)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.VisitUtils.doFullNonIteratingVisit(VisitUtils.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:448)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at it.uniteam.timeojsf.util.ApplicationSessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(ApplicationSessionExpiryFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hi, 1: sure there is not more in the stacktrace? 2: You forgot to add a RF version and your JSF implementation and 2.0.x version (JSF2.0 is just an 'api' version ) 3: The error does not seem related to your editor. That brings me to 4, can you create a [mcve] please.

Comment: Oh right, adding more text i could insert all the stacktrace, sorry. I also added the versions and my jsf page, thanks.

Comment: EDIT: i tried to upgrade to Mojarra 2.1.2 and now i do not have error anymore but the editor still not display; only if i refresh the page it works.

Comment: SOLVED: i don't know why but replacing c:forEach with ui:repeat it works!

Comment: great you solved it, but weird... You should have gotten other errors about duplicate id's since that is what would have occured... (unless only one 'proposal' would have been rendered each. Strange and I did indeed not focus on this.